# как записать Больше всего повторяющийся элемент

Tags: javascript, массивы

Нужно оставить или просто создать переменную с тем именем который больше всего повторяется,
в моем случаи должен быть переменная с результатом James [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: оно https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30966902/find-common-elements-in-1-array-using-javascript ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const names = ['James', 'James', 'Nick'];

const updatedNames = names.reduce((object, currentName) => {
  if (object[currentName] == null) {
    object[currentName] = 1;
  } else {
    object[currentName] = object[currentName] + 1;
  }

  return object;
}, {});

console.log('updatedNames', updatedNames);

console.log('updatedNames, max', Object.keys(updatedNames).reduce((a, b) => {
  return updatedNames[a] > updatedNames[b] ? a : b;
}));
```

Comment: Ветвление по идее можно заменить одним выражением вроде `object[currentName] = (object[currentName] ?? 0) + 1;`